# Android ScrollView inner layout

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I am still learning Android programming and I have a question regarding the ScrollView: below is what I would like to achieve. I don't know in advance how many thumbnails  I will place in the ScrollView but I would like them to fit the height with proper padding and spacing.

Ex: on a mobile phone

```
+-scrollview-(horizontal)------------------------+
|                                                |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|  |PIC1   |    |PIC4   |    |PIC7   |    |PIC10 |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|                                                |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|  |PIC2   |    |PIC5   |    |PIC8   |    |PIC11 |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|                                                |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|  |PIC3   |    |PIC6   |    |PIC9   |    |PIC12 |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|                                                |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

On a wider screen (tablet), there would be enough space to add a fourth line.

```
+-scrollview-(horizontal)------------------------+
|                                                |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|  |PIC1   |    |PIC5   |    |PIC9   |    |PIC13 |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|                                                |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|  |PIC2   |    |PIC6   |    |PIC10  |    |PIC14 |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|                                                |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|  |PIC3   |    |PIC7   |    |PIC11  |    |PIC15 |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|                                                |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|  |PIC4   |    |PIC8   |    |PIC12  |    |PIC16 |
|  +=======+    +=======+    +=======+    +======|
|                                                |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Any advice on how to do that? In a certain way, it is similar to the Android application list.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to go for grid view Link is [here..](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)

Or if you want to use Scrollview as your doing now just give padding to parent layout in ScrollView.
Use android:margin property of particular thumbnail to maintain space as your required.

hope this explanation works for you..

Answer (score 2):

Android provides the facility to define different user layouts for different kinds of screens. That can be used for displaying such kind of activities. The details can be found here- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: There is another answer with the same link you might have seen answer of Jasper, so it would be better not to repeat it and If you have anything to add more than the same link then you are always wel-come

Answer (score 1):

you can define different layouts for different screen sizes.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html